# Elasticsearch make a request of query_string to find words with special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a few documents with titles

```
document 1: the C# language
document 2: the C++ language
document 3: the C language
```

default mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "langs": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

the next query_sting query, gives me all 3 of the document, but I don't need the document 3

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "C# OR C++",
      "fields": [
        "title"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three documents are returned because the `title` field uses the standard analyzer. With the standard analyzer, `C#`, `C++` and `C` are all analyzed and indexed as the token `c`. Same thing when you search for `"C# OR C++"`, under the hood you end up searching `"c OR c"`.

What you need is to create a custom analyzer with a [`whitespace` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) and use it on your `title` field (precisely on the `title.tokens` sub-field).

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {               <--- custom analyzer
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "langs": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "tokens": {                <--- new sub-field using the custom analyzer
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can index your documents again:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/langs/1 -d '{"title":"The C++ language"}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/langs/2 -d '{"title":"The C# language"}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/langs/3 -d '{"title":"The C language"}'
```

Finally, you can now search on the `title.tokens` field like this and you'll get only the first two documents:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "C# OR C++",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer",         <--- use your custom analyzer
      "fields": [ "title.tokens" ]       <--- use the new field
    }
  }
}'
```